# How to write a better version of this Akka ask call with a default value?

Tags: scala, akka

I am writing a method that would '`ask`' a given actor by sending a `case class` message and I want it to return a `Future` of a given type.

The response messages are:

```
sealed abstract class StatusResponse
case class OKMaster() extends StatusResponse
case class ERRORMaster(error: String) extends StatusResponse
```

What I do currently is the following:

```
def askActor(id: Long): Future[StatusResponse] = (actor ? Request(id)).map{
   case response: StatusResponse => response
   case _ => ERRORMaster("Actor didn't send a proper StatusResponse, this error was generated instead")
}
```

This works but I still want to know if there is a better way. This still feels dirty to me, because I imagine having multiple actors of different types to ask with the same type of `StatusResponse` to expect, I would have to kind of copy paste this code. Is there another functional way of doing this? I mean, having a default value if the response isn't of expected type?

PS: I am using Akka 2.10 and Scala 2.10.3.

Comment: FYI, a no-arg case class is probably better off as a `case object`.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks, did not know that, will look into it later.

Comment: `Future` has the built in `mapTo`, is there are reason you are staying away from this?  It throws a `ClassCastException` if you get back a different type and that may be reason enough, but I just wanted to make sure you were aware of it.

Comment: @cmbaxter, I didn't know about that actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily encapsulate it:

```
val handleStatusResponse: Any => StatusResponse = {
  case response: StatusResponse => response
  case _ => ERRORMaster("Actor didn't send a proper StatusResponse, this error was generated instead")
}

def askActor(id: Long): Future[StatusResponse] = (actor ? Request(id)).map(handleStatusResponse)

def askOtherActor(id: Long): Future[StatusResponse] = (actor ? OtherRequest(id + 3)).map(handleStatusResponse)
```

Of course, it'll need some changes if your different actors have different response types or need different actions in the successful case.